# Conditions to bound the eigenvalues of a symmetric tridiagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, tridiagonal-matrices

Consider an arbitrary $n\times n$ symmetric tridiagonal matrix $M_n$ with elements

$$(M_n)_{ij} = \begin{cases} 0, \quad i=j \\ u_{\text{min(i,j)}}, \quad |i-j|=1 \\ 0, \quad \text{else} \end{cases}$$

with all subdiagonal elements $0 \leq u_i \leq 1$. I would like to find the conditions on $u_{i}$ such that the smallest eigenvalue $\lambda_{\text{min}} \geq -1$. I know that the spectrum is symmetrical about zero, and using the Gershgorin circle theorem, we can bound the eigenvalues to be within the interval $[-\max_{k} (u_k + u_{k+1}),\max_{k} (u_k + u_{k+1})] $.

From numerical tests, we seem to have the condition that $$\lambda_{\text{min}} \geq -1 \implies \max_{k} (u_k^2 + u_{k+1}^2) \leq 1.$$ Is there a way to prove this? The closest I can find is Golub's theorem from which we know that at least one eigenvalue lies in $\left[-\sqrt{u_k^2 + u_{k+1}^2}, \sqrt{u_k^2 + u_{k+1}^2}\right], k=1,\ldots,n-2$.

Edit: From numerical diagonalization, we can make the conjecture that
$$ \max_{k} (u_k^2 + u_{k+1}^2) \leq \min\{2 , \lambda_{\text{min}}^2 \} = \min\{2, (1-(\lambda_{\text{min}}+1))^2 \}$$
where the upper bound of $2$ comes from the Gershgorin theorem. Below is the numerical result. If this is true, then the above condition simply follows from it.

[image]

Comment: The claim is equivalent to $\|M_n\|\le 1.$ Since the required bound does not depend on $n,$ we can as well consider the infinite matrix $M$ of that form. For constant sequence $u_n=a$ the norm is equal $2a.$  Hence $\|M_n\|\to 2a.$ Therefore the condition $u_k^2+u_{k+1}^2=2a^2\le  1$ is not sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$v_k={\sin ( k\alpha_n) \over \sin \,\alpha_n  }, \qquad \alpha_n ={\pi\over n+1}, k=0,1,\ldots, n+1$$ Then $v_0=v_{n+1}=0$ and $$v_{k-1}+v_{k+1}=(2\cos \,\alpha_n) \,v_k\qquad k=1,2,\ldots, n$$ Thus the element $(v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n)$ is the eigenvector of the matrix $M_n$ with $u_k\equiv u$  corresponding to the eigenvalue $2u\,\cos\, \alpha_n.$ We have $$ 2u\,\cos \,\alpha_n\approx 2u,\qquad n\to \infty $$ Therefore the condition $$u_k^2+u_{k+1}^2\le 1\qquad (*)$$ is not sufficient for guarranteeing that the eigenvalues of $M_n$ are located in $[-1,1].$

Clearly the condition $$u_k+u_{k+1}\le 1,\qquad k=1,2,\ldots, n-2$$ is sufficient.

The condition $(*)$ is necessary as the euclidean  norms of the columns of $M_n$ must be less or equal $1$ which means that $$\lambda_{\min}\ge -1\implies u_k^2+u_{k+1}^2\le 1$$ Indeed the $$|\lambda_{\min}|=\lambda_{\max}=\|M_n\|$$ On the other hand $$\|M_n\|\ge \max (u_k^2+u_{k+1}^2)^{1/2}$$ Hence $$\lambda_{\min}^2\ge \max (u_k^2+u_{k+1}^2)$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have appended an edit with numerical results which suggest an even stricter condition. Can this conjecture be proven?

Comment: I have extended the answer. Perhaps the last part is satisfactiry for you. I do not quite understand what the new conjecture means, especially the constant $2$ showing up there. Do you give up the necessary assumption $u_k^2+u_{k+1}^2\le 1$ ?